# Django URLs - can't reverse url in a template

Tags: django, django-urls

I think I need a second pair of eyes.

The below example should be self explanatory.

All I need is to be able to reverse my url in the template.

/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^products/', include('products.urls')),
)
```

/products/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('products.views',
    url(r'^$', view="index", name="index"),
)
```

/templates/products/index.html

```
<a href="{% url products:index %}"> Products </a>
```

**UPDATE**

Full stacktrace - http://pastebin.com/9nLp4uP5

Answer (score 40):

The syntax changed after Django 1.5
Instead of doing this:

`<a href="{% url products_index %}"> Products </a>`

You should now do this(string instead):

`<a href="{% url 'products_index' %}"> Products </a>`

Answer (score 9):

You might try this instead:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('products.views',
    url(r'^$', view="index", name="products_index"),
)
```

/templates/products/index.html

```
<a href="{% url products_index %}"> Products </a>
```

Unless there's a compelling reason you want to namespace your urls, it's way easier just to use a more precise name in `urls.py` and then use that name in the `url` template tag.

**Update**

If the error you're getting is `No module named urls` then that means one of the urls.py files isn't being read in by the django project. Did you make sure that `products` has been added to `INSTALLED_APPS` in the `settings.py` file? Also, please include a stacktrace in your question so it will be easier to identify where the error is taking place.

Comment: Yes, I tried that too and got the same error...No module named urls

Comment: @Terra you didn't specify that you were getting that error in your original question. You should add the stacktrace to your question.

Comment: Added stacktrace to the question